# Finding a polar coordinate of the same point, but a different $r$?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

The question I'm having trouble with is..

> Plot the point $(1, \frac{\pi}{4})$. Then find
>   two other pairs of polar coordinates of this point, one with $r > 0$
>   and one with $r < 0$.

I am not sure how to find an alternative polar coordinate for $(1, \frac{\pi}{4})$ with a different $r$ that is on the same point in the graph.

I could understand if I was supposed to find a different angle $\theta$, since $\frac{\pi}{4}=2\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}=4\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}=...$ but I am not sure how to find an alternative $r$ for the same point, that isn't equal to $1$.

I thought $r$ was just the distance from the origin $O$?

Comment: For $r<0$ you can use $(-1,5\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that they want one answer with $r<0$ indicates that you should consider adding an *odd* multiple of $\pi$ to your $\theta$ value. Try $r=-1$ and $\theta = 5\pi/4$.

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider they wanted me to change $\theta$ too. Thanks!